# How do I add body text to a Bootstrap tooltip?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I'm trying to add some body text to a Bootstrap tooltip, which by default only contains a barebones title. From the relevant [Bootstrap 5 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/) it looks like the easiest way to do this is to use the `template` option:

```
template

Base HTML to use when creating the tooltip. 

The tooltip's title will be injected into the .tooltip-inner. 

.tooltip-arrow will become the tooltip's arrow. 

The outermost wrapper element should have the .tooltip class and role="tooltip".
```

However, trying to insert the body text that I want by passing it into the `template` variablea along with the rest of the JavaScript that initialises the tooltip doesn't make any difference. All that shows is the content of `bs-data-title`, and without that no tooltip renders at all (as the documentation makes clear).

My markup:

```
<div class="text-center mt-3 mb-4 mb-lg-0"><span href="#" class="badge security-tooltip" 
data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" data-bs-html="true" 
data-bs-offset="0,12" title="<h6>Secure Payment</h6>">
<i class="fas fa-lock"></i>SECURE PAYMENT</></span>
</div>
```

The JavaScript I'm using to initialise the tooltip:

```
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl, {
        template:
            '<div class="tooltip" role="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner">All payment data is handled using secure, industry-standard 256-bit encryption.</div></div>',
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong and how exactly do I accomplish this?

Answer (score -1):

I changed the JS to specify the template and title separately and it shows the tooltip. The title is specified in the JS, so I removed it from the HTML and moved it to the JS.

```js
var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl, {
        template:'<div class="tooltip" role="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner">',
      title:'<h6>Secure Payment</h6>All payment data is handled using secure, industry-standard 256-bit encryption.</div></div>',
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="text-center mt-3 mb-4 mb-lg-0"><span href="#" class="badge security-tooltip" style="color:red" 
data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" data-bs-html="true" 
data-bs-offset="0,12">
<i class="fas fa-lock"></i>SECURE PAYMENT</span>
</div>
```

Comment: No, I'm trying to render a tooltip with a title and some body text below it. Your template option misses this body text out as well as the two closing `div` tags.

Comment: I updated my answer. The tooltip now shows a title and body text. I added the div tags that were missing.